# How can I suppress the time from date time field in TFS query results?

Tags: date, tfs

Any idea how to suppress the time from showing up in query results? They are making my reports look cluttered. My custom field "Due Date" has unnecessary the 12:00:00.  I can live with it on the "Created Date" field

[image: Example]

Comment: You have no control over the output format except for the width of the columns..

Comment: That is what I was afraid of.  MS always provides 95% of a solution, but never 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the field xml like the below example:

```
<Control
FieldName="Support.TimeReceived"
Type="DateTimeControl"
Label="Time Received:"
LabelPosition="Left"
Format="Custom"
CustomFormat="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" />
```

please refer to the detailed solution in this article: http://nickhoggard.wordpress.com/2010/07/18/custom-date-format-for-the-work-item-datetimecontrol-tfs2010/.